# API Blueprint schema usage

Tags: rest, documentation, apiblueprint

We want to use [API blueprint](http://apiblueprint.org/) together with a schema. Let's say, we want to specify that PUT to a resource accepts an Account in the payload and GET on the same resource returns an Account payload. So I need to specify that Account is used in GET and PUT and I need to specify the Account itself. I do not know where to specify it, what's the canonical way? Unfortunately I was not able to find it in the examples.

Answer (score 4):

Reusing one message payload in multiple action is where can utilize the concept of a [**resource model**](https://github.com/ehedenst/raven/blob/master/blueprints/9.%20Resource%20Model.md).

Simply define a account model and then reuse it later like so:

```
# Account [/account]

+ Model (application/json)
    + Body

            { ... }

    + Schema

            { ... }

## Retrieve an Account [GET]

+ Response 200

    [Account][]


## Update an Account [PUT]

+ Request

    [Account][]

+ Response 204
```